# помогите пожалуйста с блоками

Tags: html, css

мучаюсь уже много времени никак не могу сообразить.
Как сделать так, чтоб маленький див (с красной полоской border) распологался не справа как сейчас, а слева.

```css
.divisus {
  height: 370px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
}
.painus {
margin: 2em;
    margin-left: 80%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    background: white;
    border-right:40px solid red;
}
.painus:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 265px;/* offset value to mind */
  pointer-events:none; /* takes it off the way, else negative z-index might do also */
}
```

```html
<div class="divisus">
  <div class="painus">
  </div>
</div>
```

пробовал менять местами блоки - все равно маленький оставался справа.
пример того, где должен распологаться маленький блок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эм.. Убрать `margin-left: 80%`?

Comment: не совсем. нужно, чтоб блок был за границами.

Comment: по сути тоже самое что сейчас, только зеркальное отражение

Comment: border-left вам нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого?

```css
.divisus {
  height: 370px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
  /* Чтобы показать где что */
  margin-left: 80%;
}

.painus {
  margin: 2em;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
  border-left: 40px solid red;
  transform: translateX(-80%);
}

.painus:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 265px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="divisus">
  <div class="painus"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: да)) спасибо огромное)

Comment: @DanKasper сказал же border-left

Comment: дададада спасибо)